# How to start multiple mod-mono-server4 Linux process domains at reboot time?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, apache-httpd, mono

I would like to know how to serve multiple ASP.NET applications on multiple mod-mono-server4 Linux process domains.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo ThinkStation desktop.

Here is how I plan to serve multiple ASP.NET applications on multiple mod-mono-server4 Linux process domains

```
Put the following directive at the bottom of apache2.conf

   Alias /test "/usr/share/doc/xsp/test"
   Alias /personal "/home/user/mypages"

   MonoApplications testing "/test:/usr/share/doc/xsp/test"
   <Location /test>
      MonoSetServerAlias testing
   </Location>

   MonoApplications personal "/personal:/home/user/mypages"
   <Location /personal>
      MonoSetServerAlias personal
   </Location>
```

With this approach. I am wondering how to start up multiple, n = 8 ,mod-mono-server4 Linux processes at Ubuntu 16.04 reboot time. Currently , I am using the apache2 prefork module with StartServers = 8 and  I can only start a single mod-mono-server4 Linux process domain at reboot time using systemd with an apache.service file I wrote.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I can provide more specific information on how I configured apache2 and mod-mono-server4 if requested.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this URL tonight, http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/mod_mono.8.html, my hypothesis is that we can use /etc/apache2/apache2.conf to configure any number of different mod-mono-server instances to start up at reboot time using the  MonoSetServerAlias  alias to set customize the run-time behavior of each individual mod-mono-server instance as shown below.

CONFIGURATION DIRECTIVES
       All  the  directives  but  MonoSetServerAlias  accept an optional first
       argument that is the  mod-mono-server  instance  alias  for  which  the
       directive  applies.   If  only  one  argument is provided for them, thr
       directive will apply to the 'default' mod-mono-server  instance.  Refer
       to the monodoc documentation on configuring mod_mono for more examples.

```
 MonoSetServerAlias
          Takes a server alias name. This is to be used inside <Directory>
          or <Location>.  Default value: 'default' if the directive is not
          used.

  I will test my hypothesis in 15 minutes and let everybody know my findings here. 

  Here is what I just tested.  It appears to work.

Alias /test "/var/www/firstaspnet"
Alias /personal "/var/www/secondaspnet"
AddMonoApplications testing "/test:/var/www/firstaspnet"
AddMonoApplications organicchem "/personal:/var/www/secondaspnet"
MonoListenPort 9000
<Location /test>
      SetHandler mono
      MonoSetServerAlias testing  
</Location>
<Location /personal>
     SetHandler mono
     MonoSetServerAlias organicchem
</Location>
```

I can be reached by email or cellphone about this unix-linux stack exchange topic or any other if you request with 24 hour advance notice.

Comment: This soluton has a limitation that the number of mod_mono_server4 processes started can exceed the number of apache2 server processes started at  reboot time.